# .htaccess Hijinks

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Title is vague because I can't tell you what's wrong.  My app works fine with the .htaccess file below, but during my crusade to force ssl, something broke, and now I get nothing but 500  Internal Server Errors - both on wamp and on a completely separate production host, so it's not the server.  Here's my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    #This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|cache)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 /application/errors/404.php
</IfModule>
```

The only thing that fixes this is removing the beginning "IfModule" statement.  If I get rid of that conditional and just leave the enclosed code, and delete the entire second condition, leaving only this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|cache)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Then the app works, except the entire .htaccess file is ignored completely!  Mod_rewrite is enabled, too.  The first .htaccess i posted still works fine when i switch over to my master branch in git, and I can't figure out what made the difference for the life of me.

Anyone?

Comment: 500 Server errors should create entries in your error log... Care to post?

Comment: yeah about that - i can't get error logging working either.  It's enabled in CodeIgniter, threshold is set correctly, and it's enabled/filepath given in php.ini.  Folder with the log is writeable.  No log.

Comment: I don't mean PHP error logs, I mean Apache error logs.

Comment: httpd.pid says "8156", that's the only thing modified in the apache bin folder, no other logs.

Comment: That's the process ID. Are you using the ErrorLog directives in your Apache config? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlog

Comment: Found the log. Everything hit the fan this morning and here's the first (unique, by the way) entry: `[warn] pid file C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?`.  Then this one over and over again: `C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: <IfModule takes one argument, Container for directives based on existance of specified modules`.  Investigating....

Comment: Interesting. This indicates it might be a line-break issue: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=165232

Comment: @EthanB Please post that as an answer so I can credit you - that was exactly it.  So why did Notepad++ suddenly decide to use a tab in place of a line return?  Can't tell unless you paste into Windows Notepad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your .htaccess file has correct line-breaks. Reference: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=165232.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember: 500 errors means it's Apache's fault. :)